# Plugin to extend actioncontroller for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am writing my first ever plugin for rails. The plugin is supposed to extend the actioncontroller::base

so after going through the tutorials here is what i did...

```
# Foo
class << ActionController::Base
  def function_name
```

assuming the plugin is called foo... but when i call function_name from an action, nothing happens... It seems the function_name is not even called. there is no method missing error either so i am sure the plugin has been loaded too...

m stuck real bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need include a class to ActionController.

```
module Foo
  def function_name
  end
end

ActionController::Base.send(:include, Foo)
```

Answer (score 11):

You should do this via an on_load hook:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include Foo
end
```

This will defer including the module until ActionController::Base would be loaded normally. This will avoid `AC::Base` from being prematurely loaded, which can save some load time in many Rake tasks and when loading the console.